# Pagecount of Microsoft Word documents

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Question:
How to determine the pagecount of Microsoft Word documents programmatically in Java?

First of all: 
I know POI's `SummaryInformation.getPageCount()` and I currently use it to determine the pagecount. The problem is that it simply reads the document's statistics and some MS Word versions in the past did not properly update these statistics. So there are documents around the world where this `Summary Information` is simply wrong. Therefore POI's `SummaryInformation.getPageCount()` is wrong, too.

I need to do a "real" page count which does not rely on document's statistics or I need to update the statistics with the "real" values.

The latter I can do with re-saving the document with MS Word but I hope you've some better solution for me. :-)

All Java libraries are welcome when they can solve this here. It does not have to be POI.

Comment: May be you try to read the document ..  There should be delimeter kind of thing which will tell you the end of the page .. Count of that delimeter you may know the page count

Comment: I am not really used to the word document format but as far as I know there is nothing like that. You can count explicit page breaks but that's not really helping as there may be implicit page breaks in the document, too. I would be happy someone proves me being wrong.

Comment: there is possibility to check page number in MS Word Application itself. It requires Word Interop + running Word application + opening document to check it. would it be helpful? I could give you VBA code for that which you could adjust to your needs.

Comment: When you say "real", how accurate do you need?  If your answer is 100%, then in general you'd need something which duplicates Word's page layout model 100%.

Comment: @KazJaw Thanks, we already have an OfficeConverter programmed in C# using Word, Excel and Powerpoint interop for converting Office Documents to PDF and PNG. We use it via Webservice. Of course, it is possible that we use interop for resaving the document. But that's kind of solution we like to avoid, because it costs "much" processing time.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I am afraid you're right and there is nothing like that in Java. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, it depends what you're after exactly.  Docx4j can do page counts in its PDF output, and our Enterprise Edition of docx4j can do some other stuff (eg page numbers in a table of contents, but there'll probably be some discrepancies from the numbers Word would produce).